# Write a SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

[This image contain the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03J60.jpg)
i am trying to solve this sql problem Write a SQL query to print the total rainfall in the states where the total rainfall is greater than the average of all the cities in the table 'Rainfall.

expected output:
'Maharashtra', '45'
'Kerala', '45'
'Gujarat', '11'

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Welcome Ashish to stack overflow, can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I have tried SELECT L.State, SUM(R.Rainfall) 
AS Total_Rainfall
FROM Rainfall R
JOIN Location L 
ON R.City = L.City
GROUP BY L.State
HAVING SUM(R.Rainfall) > (SELECT AVG(Rainfall) FROM Rainfall);

Comment: Please don't misuse comments to improve your question or to add clarifications. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

The sql query would be

```
SELECT * FROM Rainfall WHERE "Rainfall(dm)" > (SELECT AVG("Rainfall(dm)") FROM Rainfall) ;
```

I am not the best in SQL, But this should work.

Comment: No, it will not work. Please try out solutions BEFORE writing an answer. You can for example use fiddle sites like https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT